# How can I set a default value to the SelectListItem constructor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I set a default value to the SelectListItem constructor?  I've been trying to do:

```
  var categories = new List<SelectListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rubricsList.Count(); i++)
        {
            categories.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = rubricsList[i],
                Value = rubricsList[i],
                Selected = rubricsList[3],ToString().Equals(true)
            });
        }
```

and...

```
  Selected = rubricsList[3]).ToString().Equals(rubricsList[3])
```

EDIT:
Here's where I'm using the list:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Category, Model.Categories,"Select One")
```

...not working. I want to take a value from the list and make it a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      categories.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = rubricsList[i],
            Value = rubricsList[i],
            Selected =true           
        });
```

then in the view

```
   @{string  theSelectedOne=viewBag.selectedvalue;}
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Category, Model.Categories,theSelectedOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
categories.Add(new  SelectListItem() { Text=rubricsList[i], Value=rubricsList[i], Selected= true});
```

try this is so simple